# Автоматический перенос строки и пробел в таблице

Tags: php, html

Верстаю в PHP-файле шаблон для email-рассылки, текст внутри **p**, который находится внутри **span**, который находится в **td** внутри **tr**:

```
$msg .= '<p style="font-size: 12px; margin: 0;">Время</p>';
```

Вот что вижу в консоли Chrome:

```
    <p style="font-size:12px;margin:0;">В
 ремя</p>
```

[image: Результат в email]

В итоге там появляется ненужный пробел. Как этого избегать?

Comment: Автоматический перенос строк в редакторе кода

Answer (score 1):

Что-то в коде режет ваши строки кусками по 40 символов и вставляет перевод строки. Проблема в этом.